# How to configure independent rvmrc files across code lifecycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rvmrc

We have multiple developers contribute to source code, so it would be preferable to have multiple `.rvmrc` files for each developer. How should I automate this?

e.g.

```
dev1 uses rvm use 1.9.3@app-dev1
dev2 uses rvm use 1.9.3@app-dev2
dev3 uses rvm use 1.9.3@app-dev3
```

How do I maintain and modify .rvmrc for individual developers. Should this file be in source code repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe rvmrc file could be a bash script, therefore you could use the `USER` environment variable in there to select the gemset you want to use.

You can create an example rvmrc with the following command:

```
rvm rvmrc create @app-dev
```

Then you can easily modify the `environment_id` in the generated `.rvmrc` file to achieve the desired behavior:

```
environment_id="ruby-1.9.3@app-dev-${USER}"
```

So you could have only one rvmrc for every developer and it will select the right gemset.